# Generate Short Code for Email Confirmation using Asp.Net Identity core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

This requirement is posted somewhere else on SO, but the answer contained IUserTokenProvider which I cannot find in asp.net core 2.1.

How can I implement a emailconfirmation routine where the user does not click on a link but receives a short token (6 characters) that can safely be used to confirm the emailaddress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're configuring Identity, you can pass in a set of options, among which are token providers for various scenarios. There's a built-in `EmailTokenProvider<TUser>` that inherits from `TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider<TUser>`. You can just use this. It's actually already registered via a call to `AddDefaultTokenProviders()`, which the `AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>` and `AddDefaultIdentity<TUser>` methods internally call. As a result, you can simply use `TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider` to set it to that provider:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(o => {
    // other options: password reqs, username reqs, etc.
    o.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;
});
```